# Entity Framework- MYSQL MVC Database table exception: Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to extract a table from a database using Entity Framework and keep running into this eror:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
> HResult=0x8013193C
> Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
> Source=
> StackTrace:

Inner Exception 1:

> MySqlException: Table 'justadatabase.justadatabase.justatable' doesn't exist

I have the table in the database and the Entity framework is able to extract the model from the Database using DBFirst feature. I have unchecked the ForeignKey option.

Firstly I had to manually open the connection by including the dbE.Database.Connection.Open() in the controller. It has worked for me before without this, I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

The same for me. I tried to use the latest releases with Mysql 5.7:

Entity 6.44,
MySql.data 8.0.22,
MySql.data.entityframework 8.0.22,
Connector/NET 8.0.22,

And I had the same exception: database.database.table doesn't exist. database 2 times is a (massive) bug in mysql.data I guess.

back to:

Entity 6.20,
MySql.data 8.0.18,
MySql.data.entityframework 8.0.18,
Connector/NET 8.0.18,

And It's working.

However, I didn't try with MySQL 8.

Comment: Same by me, change from 8.0.22 to 8.0.18 and then it works

Answer (score 0):

The same has happened to me, I used the solution of placing the previous version of Entity Framework and Mysql Data